# Adding and removing animation on a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am creating a game for english typing. The words fall from the top to the edge of keyboard. For animating the fall of a label I have used:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

 label.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width - (label.frame.origin.x+label.frame.width), self.view.frame.height-self.keyboardYPosition!, label.frame.width, width)

}){(success) in

label.removeFromSuperview()

for label in self.currentLabelsArray {
                    label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                    label.removeFromSuperview()
                }
self.gameOver()


}
```

Everything goes fine. The problem I am facing is : I am calling this animation block on creation of every single label. Actually this animation block is in a function called createLabels(). And the createLabel function is called every 5 seconds using NSTimer. Once the game is over I show a view above with restart button. Now here comes the problem:

Before the game ends we might have 3-4 labels already created that are pushed into the animation block. But the very first label might end the game. I get a gameover view above it with a restart button. Once I tap restart, my game again ends because the labels created earlier are still calling the completion block of UIAnimation. I cannot restart the game unless all my labels have completed the animation.

Is there any way to remove animation once the game if completed so that the already created labels no more come into the completion block?

I have used the following code to remove the label from view and remove its animation:

```
for label in self.currentLabelsArray {
                    label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                    label.removeFromSuperview()
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess is that, perhaps you missed to invalidate the timer object.

```
for label in self.currentLabelsArray {
    label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    label.removeFromSuperview()
}
myTimer.invalidate();
```

So the timer will not call `createLabels` after the 5 sec. Once the game restarts schedule the time again.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

Another pointer could be to clear the labels array.

```
self.currentLabelsArray.removeAllObjects();
```

and call `self.gameOver()` iff, there is no request of game over in queue.

**EDIT:**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

 label.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width - (label.frame.origin.x+label.frame.width), self.view.frame.height-self.keyboardYPosition!, label.frame.width, width)

}){(success) in

//label.removeFromSuperview()

for label in self.currentLabelsArray {
     label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
     label.removeFromSuperview()
}

if(self.currentLabelsArray.count > 0) {
     self.currentLabelsArray.removeAllObjects()
     self.gameOver()
}

}
```

Comment: No I invalidated the timer in the gameOver function. But its not the timer invalidation issue. The labels created before invalidation are creating the problem. The game ends after first label. But there are 2-3 more labels that are already places on the view.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help!

Comment: What about like this ?

Comment: then the issue is somewhere else not in this snippet, because, if timer is invalidated and no labels are generating, `if(self.currentLabelsArray.count > 0) {` this line will run only once after first label meets the condition. Can we have a look at `gameover` function ?

Comment: actually I overcame the issue by assigning a tag to each label. I then deleted each label from view with that tag. I didn't get why the labels were not deleted by using: for label in self.currentLabelsArray {
     label.layer.removeAllAnimations()
     label.removeFromSuperview()
}

Comment: Have you checked the tag when deleting the labels from array ? perhaps the newly generated labels are not the part of array ?

Comment: That could be a valid point. But whenever the label is created, its added into the array